# Why did Luke accept it so easily?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker

When Vader said that " I am your Father"  Luke just believes it!  Without any research,  questions etc. Even Ben didn't reply....  Why?  Why he did accept it so easily!?  Maybe Vader would have lied to him so that he joined him,  didn't Luke think that?  Are the people in a galaxy far far away so believing?

Comment: Search your feelings, you know why.

Comment: I don't quite understand" Search your feelings, you know why."

Comment: ...you watched a very different movie than I did

Comment: Yep maybe coz i took it from my friend and probably it must have been edited

Comment: Same way Leia always knew Luke was her brother. The force works in mysterious ways

Comment: Force -  gravitational or sort of like it?

Comment: Leia did not always knew Luke was her brother!  Why would someone kiss their own brother if they know that they are siblings!

Comment: "It's you, Leia."  "I know...somehow...I've always known..." For goodness sake, watch the films and pay attention, would you?? She always knew there was a bond between her and Luke, she just never knew what it was.

Comment: Mr.  Werrf...  I have watched those since i was 1 yr old....  And there is a trilogy watching with my friends every half year....  As far as i know it George Lucas intended them not be father and son first but later it was added on or improvised....   Many girls around the world feel a brotherly bond with an unknown guy (who wants to be her boyfriend)  it is called brother - zone ( just like friend-zoned)  and Leia had thos feelings because she loved Solo more....  Not at all justified that she kissed Luke many times... Even if she had brotherly feelings for him why would she kiss him!  On the

Comment: His immediate reaction is `"No! That's not True! That's impossible!"`. Then he asks Yoda in the next film to confirm. I'm not sure I agree with your premise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### He didn't

In *Return of the Jedi*, Luke asks Yoda flat out if it was true.

> Yoda: No! Not yet. One thing remains. Vader. You must confront Vader. Then, only then, a Jedi will you be. And confront him you will.
>
> **Luke**: **Master Yoda...*is* Darth Vader my father?**
>
> **Yoda**: Er, rest, I need. Yes, rest.
>
> **Luke**: Yoda, I must know.
>
> **Yoda**: Your father he is. Told you, did he?

### He felt it was true

Although he did confirm it later, he also immediately instinctively knew it was the truth. That's why he reacted so strongly in the moment:

> **Luke**: No...that's not true...that's *IMPOSSIBLE*!
>
> **Vader**: **Search your feelings, you know it to be true!**

Luke, being at least somewhat trained in the Force, was able to 'feel' the truth once his mind was guided to it.

In *Jedi*, indeed in the scene directly after the Yoda scene, we see Luke again intuiting the truth about his family.

> **Kenobi**: That is the reason why your sister remains safely anonymous.
>
> **Luke**: *Leia*. *Leia*'s my sister.
>
> **Kenobi**: **Your insight serves you well**. Bury your feelings deep down, Luke. They do you credit, but they could be made to serve the Emperor.

Luke's knowledge of the Force, though far from complete, was quite sufficient for him to find the truth about these claims.

Comment: This does not explain the instantaneous acceptance of Vader as his father....  In the end of Empire Strikes Back they talk like father - son while Luke did not ask Yoda then...  Please improve your answer

Comment: Luke is 1) high on adrenaline, and 2) trusting his feelings. Exactly as my answer said.

Comment: Yes, the Force is very reliant on the user trusting his feelings. Though he may not know the truth to be fact until he actually got it confirmed by Yoda, he felt it to be true. Just as he felt it to be true when he realised (seemingly randomly) that Leia was his sister. It was a feeling. Normally, for us, feelings and instincts may or may not be true. But with the Force guiding him, he felt even more certain that it must be true. He just needed Yoda to confirm it beyond doubt.